# Difference between () and $()

Tags: powershell

What's the difference between

```
Write-Host (Get-Date) # just paren
```

and

```
Write-Host $(Get-Date) # dollar-paren
```

Content within the parens could be anything, just going with a simple example. Is there any difference between the two?

I consider myself reasonably experienced with PS, but it's these little things that bug me, especially during code review and the like. Has anyone come across a good source for "here is how the language works" with enough detail to derive answers to these sorts of questions?

Comment: You could try the [PowerShell Language Specification 3.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389), section 7.1.1 Grouping Parentheses and section 7.1.6 $() operator - sub-expressions

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks...make that an answer and I'll give it the green check.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The sub expression (`$(...)`) contains a `StatementBlockAst`.  It can take **any number** of statements, meaning keywords (`if`, `foreach`, etc), pipelines, commands, etc.  Parsing is similar to the inside of a named block like `begin`/`process`/`end`.

The paren expression (`(...)`) can contain a **single** `ExpressionAst` which is a limited subset of the AST.  The most notable difference between a statement and an expression is that keywords are not parsed.

```
$(if ($true) { 'It worked!' })
# It worked!

(if ($true) { 'It worked!' })
# if : The term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
# script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
# if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
# At line:1 char:2
# + (if ($true) { 'It worked' })
# +  ~~
#     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (if:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
#     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Also as others have noted, the sub expression will expand in double quoted strings.

Comment: Marking this as "the answer"; the pointer to the language spec sections from @TessellatingHeckler actually led me to the deep dive that I was after; this is a good summary.

Answer (score 3):

The `()` helps with order of operations

The `$()` helps with evaluating values inside of the `()`

For instance, if you're trying to find today's date in a string you could do the following:

```
echo "The length of Bryce is (Get-Date)"
echo "The length of Bryce is $(Get-Date)"
```

You'll see that the output is different (in one it gives you literally "(Get-Date)" whereas in the other it gives you the evaluated expression of Get-Date)

You can read more about syntax operators [here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)

Comment: I think the link you provided is along the right track, but the use within quotes is different than the use outside of quotes as in my question. Also found and am now scouring through the v 3.0 language spec (here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389) that I'm hoping will give a definitive answer.

Comment: I changed the example to use the cmdlet used in the question - is that closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: No, the processing of what's inside the parens is different when in quotes. If you did something like $x = (Get-Date) or $x = $(Get-Date), then 'echo "stuff... $x" ' it would be more in line with what I'm trying to uncover, i.e. does PS process anything different with or without the $ in front of the parens.

Answer (score 2):

Parenthesis are used to group and establish order just as they do in mathematics. Starting in PowerShell v3 you can also use them to evaluate a property of a group, such as getting the file names for the files in the current folder by running:

```
(Get-ChildItem).Name
```

A sub-expression `$()` evaluates the script within it, and then presents the output of that to be used in the command. Often times used within strings to expand a property of an object such as:

```
"Hello $($User.Name), would you like to play a game?"
```

It can also be useful when working with ComObjects, such as Excel where you may have a range that you want to test against a property of each item. While this does not work because the `Range` object does not have a `Font` property:

```
$Range.Font|Where{$_.Bold}
```

This would work, because it would output the `Range` as a collection of `Cell` objects, each of which have a `Font` property:

```
$($Range).Font|Where{$_.Bold}
```

You can think of sub-expressions as being a script within your script, since they can be several commands long, and the entire thing is evaluated at once so that the end output can be used for the parent command.