# How to pipe output from foreach, in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pipe the output from a `foreach` loop into a format command but it does not work. The reason I think is possible is because this works.

```bsh
$op = foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -File)) {
    $file |
    Get-Member |
    Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "Method" -and $_.Definition -like "*system*" } |
    Select-Object -Property Name, MemberType
}

$op | Format-List
```

If I can assign the whole output to a variable, and pipe the variable into another command, **why does the following NOT work?**

```
(foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -File)) {
    $file |
    Get-Member |
    Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "Method" -and $_.Definition -like "*system*" } |
    Select-Object -Property Name, MemberType
}) | Format-List
```

Of course I tried without parents, but ultimately I think if anything, the parents make sense. It is like `$file in (Get-ChildItem -File)` where it evaluates the expression in the parents and uses the result as the actual object

Is there a way to make this work?

*please note that the code is not supposed to achieve anything (else) than giving an example of the mechanics*

Comment: Powershell distinguishes between Command parsing mode and Expression parsing mode - you've got both cases...

Comment: If you use `$(foreach ...)`, it'll work.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason or differences between `$()` and `()`.  I've asked questions to this tag in the past, but no one was able to give me a concise answer.  I just know wrapping things in a subexpression causes them to output differently.

Comment: It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274532/difference-between-and)...

Comment: @PeterSchneider Very nice.  Your google-fu is stronger than mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` does not have an output you can capture (besides the sugar you've found with variable assignment), but you can gather all the objects returned by wrapping it in a subexpression:

```
$(foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -File) {
    # ...
}) | Format-List
```

This same pattern can be used for `if` and `switch` statements as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it, without waiting for the whole foreach to finish.  It's like defining a function on the fly:

```
& { foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -File) {
      $file |
      Get-Member |
      Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "Method" -and $_.Definition -like "*system*" } |
      Select-Object -Property Name, MemberType
    } 
} | format-list
```

By the way, `$( )` can go anywhere `( )` can go, but it can enclose multiple statements separated by newlines or semicolons.

Also, you can pipe it directly:

```
Get-ChildItem -File |
Get-Member |
Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "Method" -and $_.Definition -like "*system*" } |
Select-Object -Property Name, MemberType | 
Format-List
```

Comment: Ah, nice use of IIFE.  Forgot you could do that.  It just has extra overhead of creating a new scope and managing invocation

Comment: ok, nice! I knew this technique but a bit different.  `1..3 | & {Process { $_*3 }}` It makes sense now. I learned yesterday that a function will by default use the end block. That is why in my example here I need process explicitly but when you use it, the end block is correct and you return the result which is pipable. But why does  it not need to wait for the foreach to finish?

Comment: I don't know why.  I just know that it does.

Comment: @TheFool pipeline and scriptblock black magic; it's not seen as a single command like a subexpression